# Unable to change from C to other local disk using cmd

Tags: windows

The command `F:` is not changing the prompt to local drive from **c** to **f**.
Before it would happen easily but suddenly the command has stopped working . 
What is the reason behind this behaviour?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `/d` switch:

```
cd /d f:
```

or just type

```
f:
```

without the `/d` switch, the directory is changed, but not the disk, if you switch the disk you'll see that the directory has changed:

```
c:\srv> cd f:
F:\

c:\srv> cd f:\dropbox

c:\srv> f:

f:\Dropbox>
```

Comment: Yes,but can you explain the behavior of 'F:/' showing with 'cd F:' and then changing back to 'C:/' ?

Comment: @BoRRis I've updated my answer